# How can i handle window authentication pop up in protractor using cucumber and type script

Tags: typescript, protractor, cucumber

I am new in to the protractor and i am writing a script where when i click an element it will open window authentication pop up and i have to pass my user id and password to access the web page.

Please help me how can i handle this as autoit is not working here for me , is there any specific piece of code i have to add in my script to handle this pop up

[image]

Comment: has been answered many times on stack overflow. But @naz.kir is on point

Comment: but its not working for chrome, is there any way to handle this on chrome @naz.kir

Answer (score 1):

You can't actually handle this popup but you can avoid it. We have to pass the user name and password along with the URL to handle the authentication pop in protractor. Please find the syntax to pass the username and password

```
browser.get(protocol://Usename:Password@URL Address);
```

For example

```
browser.get(https://selenium:webdriver@chercher.tech/auth);
```

Complete program to handle Authentication popup

```
describe('Protractor Typescript Demo', function() {
    it('Alerts operation', function() {
        browser.get("https://selenium:webdriver@chercher.tech/auth");
        browser.getTitle().then(function(title){
            if(title == "Authentication Successful"){
                console.log("Login successful")
            }else{
                console.log("Login Falied")
            }
        })
    });
});
```

If login is successful, you will see the below page on the browser.

Copy/pasted from https://chercher.tech/protractor/alerts-popups-protractor (Authentication Pop Up section)

Comment: but its not working for chrome, is there any way to handle this on chrome @naz.kir